# How to I just pull the numbers out of a text file and set it to an array? Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have a text file that contains this:
List of values
531
70
5
17
22
876

What I am trying to do is merge sort those values. I know the code to merge sort an array but I am just having trouble putting it into an array. Here is my code.

```
f = open("testNumbers.txt", "r")
lines=f.readlines()
```

When I run it I get:
['List of values\n', '531\n', '70\n', '5\n', '17\n', '22\n', '876']

How do I remove everything and just leave me with numbers? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this if there are strings in between too.

```
f = open("testNumbers.txt", "r")
lines=f.readlines()
lines = [num.strip() for num in lines if num.strip().isdigit()]
```

Or this when text only at the beginning:

```
f = open("testNumbers.txt", "r")
lines=f.readlines()
lines = [num.strip() for num in lines[1::]]
```